# How to remove variable from animation code

Tags: javascript, local-variables

I am trying to remove this namespaced-scoped variable from the code.

How would I be able to do that?

Is this able to be done?

**Local Variable:** `let currentPlayButton = {};`

https://jsfiddle.net/hxar8w1g/

```
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {

  let currentPlayButton = {};

  function animationEndHandler(evt) {
    const animationName = evt.animationName;

    if (animationName === "initial-fade") {
      body.classList.remove("initial-fade");
      showCover(currentPlayButton);
    }
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    currentPlayButton = evt.currentTarget;
    body.classList.add("initial-fade");
  }

}());
```

**Full Function:**

```
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
  const config = {};
  const body = document.body;
  let currentPlayButton = {};

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function hideAll(elements) {
    elements.forEach(hide);
  }

  function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
    const allBackgrounds = document.querySelectorAll(backgroundSelector);

    function hideBackground(background) {
      background.classList.add("bg1");
    }
    allBackgrounds.forEach(hideBackground);
  }

  function resetButtons(buttonSelector) {
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

    function hideButton(button) {
      button.classList.add("isOpen");
    }
    allButtons.forEach(hideButton);
  }

  function resetPage() {
    resetBackground("body");
    resetButtons(".outer");
  }

  function markAsPlayed(played) {
    played.classList.add("played");
  }

  function showCover(playButton) {
    hideAll(config.containers);
    resetPage();
    markAsPlayed(playButton);
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
    show(cover);
  }

  function animationEndHandler(evt) {
    const animationName = evt.animationName;

    if (animationName === "initial-fade") {
      body.classList.remove("initial-fade");
      showCover(currentPlayButton);
    }
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    currentPlayButton = evt.currentTarget;
    body.classList.add("initial-fade");
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function playButtonHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }

  function init(selectors) {
    config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
    addClickToButtons(playButtons);
    body.addEventListener("animationend", animationEndHandler);
  }

  return {
    addCoverHandler,
    init
  };
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not global, it's local to `makeManageCover` - which is just fine, there shouldn't be anything to worry about. Global variables are problematic, but namespaced-scoped variables are extremely common and can be difficult or impossible to eliminate.

But if you wanted to remove it from being in the top-level scope of `makeManageCover`, you could make an IIFE, declare it inside the IIFE, and return both the `animationEndHandler` and `coverClickHandler`. This is the exact same technique you're using for the whole `manageCover`, only on a smaller scale.

```
const { animationEndHandler, coverClickHandler } = (() => {
    let currentPlayButton = {};
    function animationEndHandler(evt) {
        const animationName = evt.animationName;
        if (animationName === "initial-fade") {
            body.classList.remove("initial-fade");
            showCover(currentPlayButton);
        }
    }
    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        currentPlayButton = evt.currentTarget;
        body.classList.add("initial-fade");
    }
    return { animationEndHandler, coverClickHandler };
})();
```